# Are the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^{2})$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^{3})$ isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, ring-isomorphism

Are the ring $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^{2})$ and $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^{3})$ isomorphic? Justify your answer

I have no idea to do this question, can anyone help me?

Comment: You should not ask an "I have no idea" type of question, but rather include your thoughts and attempts.

Comment: @CaptainLama I cannot construct the first step, so I have no idea to prove this question...

Comment: Did you try to compare with similar situations that you can solve? To exploit properties of rings that you know and that might be the same or not in those two rings? To think about what part of your course this exercise was given in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there an element $y\in\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$, like $x$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^3)$, such that $y^2\neq 0$ but $y^3=0$? Well,
$$y=a+bx$$
for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Necessarily $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$.
$$y^2=a^2+2abx$$
and
$$y^3=a^3+3a^2bx$$
Neither $y^2$ nor $y^3$ is $0$, so there is no such element in $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$. Hence the two rings cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: Why $y^{2}=a^{2}+2abx$ rather than $y^{2}=a^{2}+2abx+b^{2}x^{2}$? Similar question for $y^{3}=a^{3}+3a^{2}bx$

Comment: @rayray Because $x^2=0$. Your expressions are also equal, but leaving the higher order terms there is redundant.

Comment: @rayray218 Simpler: in $\Bbb R[x]/x^2\!:\  y^3 = 0\Rightarrow\ y^2 = 0,\, $ since in $\Bbb R[x]\!:\ x^2\mid y^3\color{#c00}\Rightarrow x\mid y\Rightarrow\, x^2\mid y^2,\,$ since $\color{#c00}{x\ \rm is\ prime}$ in $\Bbb R[x],\,$ by $\Bbb R$ a domain. $\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

There's always something for you to try to do.

For example, what do the elements of $\mathbb R [x]/(x^2)$ and $\mathbb R [x]/(x^3)$ look like? If you can answer this, then it problem becomes much clearer.

**Hint:** To find elements of $\mathbb R [x]/(q(x))$: for any $f(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$, do polynomial division with $q(x)$, so that we may write $f(x) = g(x) q(x) + r(x)$, for some $r(x)$ with degree less than $q(x)$...